# Mysql search query matching field name

Tags: mysql, search, sql-like

I need help making a search mysql query in multiple fields and i also want it to return the field(s) where the keywords match with the field value:

example:

```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT Name, MATCHFIELD FROM `employes` WHERE `Name` LIKE '%$keyword%' || `Prenom` LIKE '%$keyword%' || `Telephone` LIKE '%$keyword%' || `Telephone2` LIKE '%$keyword%'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

 echo $row['name'].':'.$row['MATCHFIELD'];
}
```

MATCHFIELD is not a field in my database, it has to be the  name of the field where the "LIKE" found something

this is supposed to return something like this: "John bishop 332521455"

the number "332521455" could be in any field.

This code is a part of a autosuggest script
so the query has to return only rows where a field matchs with a field value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get matching column & its value MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370706/get-matching-column-its-value-mysql)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that example doesnt have a clause "WHERE" , i need only rows where a field is matching with the keyword

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution:

this is how  i did:

SELECT Id,Nom, 
CASE
 WHEN Telephone LIKE '%$keyword%' THEN Telephone
 WHEN Telephone2 LIKE '%$keyword%' THEN Telephone2
        END AS MatchingColumn
FROM employes
WHERE `Nom` LIKE '%$keyword%' || `Prenom` LIKE '%$keyword%' || `Telephone` LIKE '%$keyword%' || `Telephone2` LIKE '%$keyword%'

MatchingColumn is the field name with the value where the LIKE matchs

Thanks for the help